# Setting Row Height on the Matrix Control in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, height, row

I am working on SSRS 2005, I am using a Matrix control and am able to set the data as I want to display it. My problem is that I want to assign different Row Height to different Rows. I am unable to do so. The maximum row height is automatically applied to every row.

Is it possible to assign different row heights?

Regards

ASP

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since 2005 "snaps" the content to the parent row. What you can do is to add a table inside the matrix cell and size its rows.